# Query by date with JS in Back4App

Tags: javascript, react-native, parse-platform, back4app, parse-javascript-sdk

I've got dates in my Back4App backend with times defaulting to midnight (start of day) e.g.

> 5 May 2019 at 00:00:00 UTC

I'm trying to use this date as a filter in my query. Without the filter, the object is retrieved with this date in the following format

```
"departureDate": Object {
      "__type": "Date",
      "iso": "2019-05-04T00:00:00.000Z",
    }
```

While the bulti-in back4App dates are showing as follows:

`"createdAt": "2019-03-09T13:28:10.262Z"`

In my query I use the following criteria:

```
const todaysDate = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0);
const InboundTrain = Parse.Object.extend('Inbound');
const query = new Parse.Query(Inbound);
query.greaterThanOrEqualTo("departureDate", todaysDate);
```

However, the query returns nothing. I've run out of ideas, anyone's seen this behaviour before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just to change this line here:

```
const todaysDate = new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0));
```